# How do I get rid of security warning in IT Hit Ajax File Browser when opening docs?

Tags: webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

When I double click on a file to open a `non-MS Office document` from *IT Hit Ajax File Browser* I get the following warning:

`Some files can harm your computer. If file information looks suspicious or you do not fully trust the source, do not open the file.`

Can I suppress this warning somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning comes from Java Applet and is similar to the warning raised by Microsoft Office web browsers add-ins and ActiveX when user opens MS Office documents. It is provided for consistency with MS Office add-ins and ActiveX behavior.

The the applets sources are shipped as part of IT Hit Ajax File Browser. So to remove it you will need to change the applet sources, compile and sign the applet with your code signing certificate.